# Remove an item from a local collection without deleting

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have the following setup:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int FooId { get; private set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public int FooId { get; private set; }
    public Foo Foo { get; private set; }

    private readonly List<Baz> _bazes= new List<Baz>();
    public IReadOnlyCollection<Baz> Bazes => _bazes.AsReadOnly();

    public Baz AddBaz(Baz baz)
    {
        _bazes.Add(baz);
    }

    public void RemoveBaz(Baz baz)
    {
        baz.Delete();
        _bazes.Remove(baz);
    }
}

public class Baz
{
    public int BazId { get; private set; }

    public int FooId { get; private set; }
    public Foo Foo { get; private set; }

    public int QuxId { get; private set; }
    public Qux Qux { get; private set; }

    public DateTime? DateDeleted { get; private set; }

    public void Delete()
    {
        DateDelete = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }
}

public class Qux
{
    public int QuxId { get; private set; }
}
```

This is all manage through EF Core:

On Foo ->

```
builder.HasKey(k => k.FooId);
builder.Property(p => p.FooId).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
```

On Bar ->

```
builder.HasKey(k => k.FooId);
builder.Property(p => p.FooId).ValueGenerateNever();

builder.HasMany(hm => hm.Baz).WithOne().HasForeignKey(fk => fk.FooId);
```

On Baz ->

```
builder.HasQueryFilter(qf => !qf.DateDeleted.HasValue);

builder.HasKey(k => k.BazId);
builder.Property(p => p.BazId).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

builder.HasOne(ho => ho.FooId).WithMany().HasForeignKey(fk => fk.FooId);
builder.HasOne(ho => ho.QuxId).WithMany().HasForeignKey(fk => fk.QuxId);
```

On Qux ->

```
builder.HasKey(k => k.QuxId);
builder.Property(p => p.QuxId).ValueGenerateOnAdd();
```

All of this works exactly as desired, apart from when trying to delete a Baz. As I only want to soft delete I call Baz.Delete(), but I also need to remove it from Bar._bazes otherwise my unit tests still show it is on the object. The issue with this is that it's trying to hard delete Baz from the database, which I don't want, and I am getting an error:

*"The association between entity types 'Foo' and 'Baz' has been severed but the relationship is either marked as 'Required' or is implicitly required because the foreign key is not nullable. If the dependent/child entity should be deleted when a required relationship is severed, then setup the relationship to use cascade deletes.  Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the key values."*

Is there any way to resolve this? In an ideal scenario Baz should ONLY soft delete but still be removed from the collection of bazes on Bar

Comment: Personally I wouldn't bother... But you could override SaveChanges / SaveChangesAsync and run both pre & post save methods to turn a delete into an update, then remove from tracked changes respectively.

Comment: Hi @JGillardCCG,any update about this case?

Comment: We elected to just hard delete Baz due to time constraints

Comment: In my opinion, the only reason for your hard deletion is to execute the `Savechange` method after deleting `Baz` in your local collection, which will cause the database to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will perform a hard delete because you call the `Context.Savechange` method after calling the `RemoveBaz` method.

After `RemoveBaz`, your `List<Baz>` has removed `Baz`, and then you perform `SavaChange`, which will perform a hard delete.

You should write your `RemoveBaz` method after `Savechange`.

Change your `RemoveBaz` like this:

```
public void RemoveBaz(Baz baz)
    {
        _bazes.Remove(baz);
    }
```

Then the order of deletion should be `baz.Delete()`=>`SaveChange`=>`bar.RemoveBaz(baz)`

This is your issue test:

[image]

This is my solution test:
[image]

Comment: Did you read the question? He's already done that bit.

Comment: If my answer is useful to you, you can mark it as answer,that will help people who encounter the same problem in the future.